# How to redirect a person to a website after prompting?

Tags: vbscript

I want to redirect a person when he clicks "yes" on

```
X=MsgBox("Message Description",4+16,"Title")
```

After he/she clicks "Yes" he will be redirected to www.google.com, and if they click "no" the .vbs will just exit.

this will help me alot

Comment: Is the person supposed to be teleported to one of Google's data centers? Or what exactly do you mean by "redirected"? In a plain VBScript with just the line above there's nothing to redirect. You need to provide a whole lot more context for someone to be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
 X = MsgBox ("Blah blah", VBYesNo, "Title")
    If X = vbYes then
        location.href = "www.google.com"
    end If
```

Comment: it shows error at line: 3 char : 9 object required : 'window'

Comment: funny I think it should work, but can't test where I am try with the edit using location.href instead